Change the select box button text in React
So I have an array of JSON where object looks like this -
[
    {
      "country_code": "AF",
      "country_name": "Afghanistan",
      "country_flag": "",
      "phone_number_code": "+93",
    },
    {
      "country_code": "AL",
      "country_name": "Albania",
      "country_flag": "",
      "phone_number_code": "+355",
    },
    ...
]

So I have a select and option tags and I want to render in this way.

Label should be - country_flag + phone_number_code + country_name
Value should be - phone_number_code
The value after selection from dropdown in the select button should be - country_flag + phone_number_code.

I'm stuck in acheiving this functionality. Label and value I understand how to do. How to acheive the 3rd point? Like I tried via manipulating DOM but I think it's not the right way to do in React. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.
The case I want (The 3rd Point)
The case I want for label in dropdown
And value is +91

In the third point, do you mean that the text of the selected option should be different from the text of the remaining options?  It's not really clear to me what you're describing.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Do your select options already exist  or are you modifying them? You should include the code that you use to retrieve or create the select(s) and options in question. I don't think I'd use an emoji as an option value. I would likely use the country code as the key and use that to retrieve the flag or phone number code if needed.

Hi @David I have updated the question with images can you please check

I think good way to achieve something like this would be to use .map function to create components from this data.
For example:
import countries from './countries.json'

const SelectComponent = () => {
   return (
      <>
          <label for="country-select">Choose a country: </label>
          <select id="country-select">
              {countries.map(country => (
                  <option key={country.country_code value={country.phone_number_code}>{country.contry_flag} {country.phone_number_code} {country.country_name} />
              )}
          </select>

      </>
   }

Hope this helps!
